# My Angular 6 routing returns 404 after page refresh behind Nginx proxy

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, nginx

I have my **angular** app running inside **docker** that exposed on port 83, and I also have a **spring-boot rest** app inside another docker that exposed on port 8083.

In the host server I have one Nginx server that reroute every requests using below config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:83;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name rest.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8083;
    }
}
```

With above config, every request that uses **mydomain.com** will goes to my Angular 6 app, and every request that uses **rest.mydomain.com** will goes to my spring-boot rest app.

In the index page of my angular, I have a **search form** which will trigger the Routing module to open a **search result page**.

My **app-routing.module.ts** is like below:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomePgComponent } from './home-pg/home-pg.component';
import { ResultsPgComponent } from './results-pg/results-pg.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", component: HomePgComponent },
  { path: "search", component: ResultsPgComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(
    routes,
    { enableTracing: true }
  )],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
export const RoutingComponents = [
  HomePgComponent, 
  ResultsPgComponent
];
```

And the trigger on my **search form** is like below:

```
onSearchBtnClk(el) {
    if (el.value.length > 0) {
      console.log(">>> SEARCH ARGS = " + el.value);
      this.router.navigate(['/search'], { queryParams: { q: el.value }});
      this.newArgsEmitter.emit(el.value);
    }
}
```

Everything works well, when I click the search button, my angular will open the **search result page** and shows the results.

My problem is, whenever I click **REFRESH** button on the browser, instead of a search page result, it shows **404 page**. Why is this happen?

Any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: on refresh does any error show in console?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add a `try_files` statement, but because you are using a proxy_pass this makes things a bit more complicated. This is untested but you can try this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html @proxy;    

    location @proxy {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:83;
    }
}
```

> The “@” prefix defines a named location. Such a location is not used for a regular request processing, but instead used for request redirection. They cannot be nested, and cannot contain nested locations.

[read more](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)

Comment: what is the @proxy for? any documentation?

Comment: @Niton it's just a name I used in the `location` declaration, so I can point to it from the `try_files`. I could have named it `@teddybear` and it would have worked. You can read about it [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)

Answer (score 2):

It's because an Agular app is a single page app (SPA).

When you refresh the app your nginx config needs to always serve up index.html.

Currently, when you refresh say for example /some-path

nginx, by default, will look for a file called /some-path.html which obviously does not exist.

To always serve up index.html you need to tweak your nginx.conf something like this:

[Nginx config for single page app with HTML5 App Cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32593739/nginx-config-for-single-page-app-with-html5-app-cache)

Here's an excerpt from the accepted answer at that link:

```
root /files/whatever/public;
index index.html;

location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html =404;
}

# Proxy requests to "/auth" and "/api" to the server.
location ~ ^/(auth|api) {
    proxy_pass http://application_upstream;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

Also, just Google configure Nginx to serve Single Page Application