# Angular 9 + Ngnix = 404 when deeplinking

Tags: angular, nginx, angular9, nginx-location, loopback4

I'm creating an `Angular 9` application with a `Loopback 4` backend using `nginx`.

When using `ng serve` I can navigate to different pages and refresh the page without issue. However after pushing to the staging server, I can navigate the app but if I refresh any page that isn't `staging.mydomain.com/` I get a 404 error.

I've tried adding `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;` to the `location` section of my `nginx.conf` file, but when I do that the even the index page doesn't load any more.

Below you'll see the the `server` section of my `nginx.conf` file:

```
server {

  listen       443 ssl http2;
  listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name  staging.mydomain.com; # managed by Certbot
  root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/staging.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/staging.mydomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

  # Load configuration files for the default server block.
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;

  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;

  location / {
    #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3004;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Conneciton 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }

}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name staging.mydomain.com;
  return 301 https://staging.mydomain.com$request_uri;
}
```

Is anybody able to provide some guidance to get my deep links working correctly?

Comment: Does this solve your problem
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52699493/7743705

Comment: No. When I add that above `location` and try to load the site it displays the "Welcome to nginx on the Amazon Linux AMI!" welcome page (not my site)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ouch, this wasn't an `nginx` issue. It was a `Loopback` configuration issue.

I added the following to my `application.ts` file to forward all uncaught requests to `index.html` for Angular to capture and process.

```
this.static('*', path.join(__dirname, '../public/index.html'));
```

Once I added that static path, everything started working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an additional `/` at the end of your proxy-pass statement.

```
location / {
    #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3004/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Conneciton 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
```

- Note the dire importance of the **trailing** slash in `proxy_pass`, which automatically alters the $uri variable to have the `/foo` on the front-end correspond with `/` on the backend. No need for an explicit rewrite directive.

Comment: I just tried that, but it didn't work I'm afraid. I still got the 404 error page. I also tried un-commenting the `try_files` but that resulted in a blank white page.